# Describe an infinite set S in which every element is an infinite set.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Any examples where every element of an infinite set is also an infinite set?

Comment: There are of course infinitely many examples.  I encourage you to look at the examples given by other people to build intuition, but I strongly encourage you once you are done to *come up with your own example*.  Part of the point of this exercise I'm sure is to rehearse your creativity.

Answer (score 1):

$$\{\mathbb Q+r\mid r\in \mathbb R\setminus \mathbb Q\},$$
where $$\mathbb Q+r=\{q+r\mid q\in\mathbb Q\}.$$

---

Also $$\{\mathbb N^k\mid k\in\mathbb N\setminus \{0\}\}.$$

and many others...

Answer (score 1):

Take the power set of $\Bbb N$ and delete all the finite sets.

Answer (score 1):

$$\{(-\infty,r]\mid r\in\mathbb R\}$$

Answer (score 0):

Choose any infinite set $A$ (say $A=\mathbb{N}$ or $A=\mathbb{R}$) or whatever.

Then take $B = \{A\times \{n\} : n\in\mathbb{N}\}$.

Clearly $B$ is an infinite set and it's elemenets are infinite sets.

You can of course change $\mathbb{N}$ with any other infinite set.

Answer (score 0):

For instance, the set of all functions $\Bbb N\to\Bbb \{0,1\}$.

Comment: @ParasKhosla Are you real? In my book, there are infinitely many functions with domain $\Bbb N$ and codomain $\{0,1\}$, and every such function is an infinite set.

Comment: You could add that in your answer that there are infintely many such sets and write few one or two more examples.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in a comment, there are very many possible examples. One of the simplest which is actually useful is the set of positive multiples of positive integers. For each integer $\,n>0\,$ there is associated with it the set of all positive integer multiples of $\,n.\,$ Thus the set

$$ \{ \{1,2,3,4,\dots\},\  \{2,4,6,8,\dots\},\  \{3,6,9,12,\dots\},\ \dots\} $$

is an infinite set of infinite sets because there are countably infinite number of positive integers and the multiples of each positive integer is also a countably infinite set.